Calculate the percentage change between successive observations rowwise in a dataframe, under specific conditions
I have this hypothetical dataframe
 df<- data.frame(a_13=c(NA, 1, 2),
                    a_12=c(NA, 0, 3), 
                    a_11=c(0, 0,NA),
                    a_10=c(0, 8,10))
    df 
  a_13 a_12 a_11 a_10
1   NA   NA    0    0
2    1    0    0    8
3    2    3   NA    10

I want to calculate the percentage change between successive obs rowwise in the above dataframe. In particular,
I want to augment the above dataframe with 3 additional columns (I_13, I_12, I_11), where each
row of these new columns will result  from successive percentage change of the elements of the corresponding
row of columns  (a_13, a_12, a_11), that is,

I_13 results from (a_13/a_12-1)*100%
I_12 results from (a_12/a_11-1)*100%
I_11 results from (a_11/a_10-1)*100%

where for the percentage change, the following conditions must hold

If a_{t}=NA and a_{t-1}=NA, then     (a_{t}/a_{t-1}-1)*100%=NA
If  a_{t-1}=0 or NA, then      (a_{t}/a_{t-1}-1)*100%="#"
If a_{t}=NA and a_{t-1}>0, then a_{t}/a_{t-1}=0  and so  (a_{t}/a_{t-1}-1)*100%=-100%

So my new data frame should be
df_D
    a_13 a_12 a_11 a_10   I_13   I_12     I_11
1   'NA   'NA' '0'   '0'   'NA'    '#'     '#'
2    '1   '0'  '0'   '8'   '#'     '#'    '-100%'
3    '2'  '3'  'NA' '10' '-33.333%' '#' '-100%'

I tried something like
library(scales) 
df[sub("^a", "I", names(df))] <- cbind( percent( unlist( (df[-ncol(df)] - df[-1])/df[-1] ) ) )

But it does not work.
My real dataframe contains hundreds of thousands of rows and a_13 up to a_1. So a more general code would help.

dplyr::across seems like an obvious candidate, taking note of the .names argument.

Just a side note, but mixing numbers and characters ("#") is rarely a good idea.

Thank you. I just modified accordingly my question.

The following approach should work:

Create a new data.frame with 2 columns act and prev which represent the actual  and  the previous  period.
Calculate the ratios  according to your requirements.
pivot_wider the result to obtain the desired format.

calc_perc <- function(act, prev) {
  case_when(
    is.na(act) & is.na(prev) ~ NA_character_,
    is.na(prev) | abs(prev) <= .Machine$double.eps ~ "#",
    is.na(act) & prev > 0 ~ "-100%",
    TRUE ~ paste0(round(100 * (act / prev - 1), 2L), "%")
  )
}

res <- df %>% 
  reframe(
    var = rep(names(.), each = n()),
    act = c_across(-c(starts_with("var"))), 
    prev = lead(act, n())
  ) %>% 
  mutate(I = calc_perc(act, prev)) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number(), 
         .by = var) 

Now we just need to use pivot_wider:
res %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = var,
    values_from = c(act, I),
    id_cols = rn,
    names_glue = "{str_sub(.value, 1L, 1L)}_{str_extract_all(var, '[0-9]+$')}"
  ) %>%
  select(-rn, -last_col())

# # A tibble: 3 × 7
#    a_13  a_12  a_11  a_10 I_13    I_12  I_11 
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr> <chr>
# 1    NA    NA     0     0 NA      #     #    
# 2     1     0     0     8 #       #     -100%
# 3     2     3    NA    10 -33.33% #     -100%

